# Angular 2+: Input decorator not reflecting checkbox

Tags: html, css, angular, checkbox, angular2-forms

I have a component

timeBoxSelector
HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="selected">
```

TS:

```
@Component({
   ...
})
export class TimeboxComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() selected: boolean;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Selected: ', this.selected);
    }
}
```

Now, when I create

```
<app-timebox selected="false"><app-timebox/>
<app-timebox selected="true"><app-timebox/>
```

In both cases, the checkbox initially appears as selected. Why is this the case, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, you are binding non empty strings, which are [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) values. Use the [brackets](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#remember-the-brackets) notation to tell Angular that the bound value is to be evaluated as a Javascript expression:

```
<app-timebox [selected]="false"><app-timebox/>
<app-timebox [selected]="true"><app-timebox/>
```

Comment: *"... to be evaluated as a **JavaScript** expression"* would be more helpful for future users with a similar problem.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu - Thanks for the suggestion. I made the change.